# Trying to collect output from multiple statments

Tags: bash, pipe, output, echo, cat

Is there a way to wrap all of this write (pun intended) no only ``` is in temp.md

```
echo "\`\`\`" && cat temp.txt && echo "\`\`\`" > temp.md
```

Comment: How  is question related to any of the tags it is tagged with?

Comment: So sorry, was recycled from a question I was going to post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simpler (no backslashes needed) to use single-quotes:

````
{ echo '```' && cat temp.txt && echo '```'; }  >temp.md
````

Alternatively, if you want finer control over the output format, `printf` is handy:

````
printf '```\n%s\n```\n' "$(cat temp.txt)" >temp.md
````

#### Why use single-quotes?

From `man bash`:

> Enclosing  characters  in  single  quotes  preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes.  A single quote may
>   not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.

In other words, you can put anything inside single quotes, except for a single quote, and it will be preserved unchanged.  No escapes needed.

By contrast, the shell processes characters inside of double quotes.  From `man bash`:

> Enclosing characters in double quotes preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of $, 
>   `,
>   \, and, when history expansion is enabled, !.

For example, inside double quotes, the shell will perform variable substitution, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion. Do not use double quotes unless you want these things to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

```
(echo "\`\`\`" && cat temp.txt && echo "\`\`\`") > temp.md
```